# How to understand this rx-swift map function

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have some textfileds in my viewcontroller. And use rx-swift to observer the .editingDidBegin event.

I want to judge which textfield sends event.

```
let tags = txtFieldArray.map{($0.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin), $0.tag)}
            .map{obs, tag in obs.map{tag}}
let value = Observable.merge(tags)
        value.bind {[weak self] (tags) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            if let view = strongSelf.ipEnteryView.viewWithTag(tags) as? UITextField {
                strongSelf.viewMode.changeTextFiledBottomColor(view, true)
            }
            }.disposed(by: disposedBag)
```

The txtFieldArray's first map return a array, element is tuples(as my understand),first is controlEvent, second is a int value. What i don't understand is the second map function. Obs is contrlEvent type. Why obs.map{tag} return a observable. And how to understand map{obs, tag in obs.map{tag}}?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The output is:

```
obs.map{ tag }
```

which represents

```
$0.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin).map { $0.tag }
```

It's replacing a the .editingDidBegin control sequence with whatever that field's tag value is.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more detail of how convert controlEvent to observable(Int).

Answer (score 0):

`obs.map { tag }` returns an Observable because the signature of the function is:

`ObservableType.map<Result>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) throws -> Result) -> RxSwift.Observable<Result>`

Since `map` returns an Observable, `ops.map { tag }` returns an Observable.

`.map{obs, tag in obs.map{tag}}` takes an Array of `(ControlEvent<()>, Int)`, goes through each element converts it into an `Observable<Int>`.

`map` is just a function that transforms the subtype of the functor it is called on. So the first map transforms an Array of X into Array of Y and the second map transforms an ObservableType of X into an Observable of Y.

Comment: Thank you. `Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
    .map { $0 * 10}
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)`  . It go through each element and multify 10. So what is the detail of obs.map{tag}, convert ContrlEvent<()> to Observable(Int).